# XFCE 4 panel show delay

Tags: xfce, main-desktop-panel

I'm using Arch Linux with XFCE 4.10. I have two auto hide panels - one on the bottom (Windows style) and one on top for status information (temperature, fans etc). Is there a way to set some delay, to define how much time mouse pointer has to be still before a panel shows up? Currently, when I move my pointer to the bottom, "main" panel gets up without delay (and that's fine). But when my pointer touches top border (for any reason), upper panel show up and it's annoying.

Is there a way to change that, to set a delay (even better, set a delay for just one panel)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I have added

```
`style "xfce-panel-window-style"
 {
   # Time in miliseconds before the panel will unhide on an enter event
   XfcePanelWindow::popup-delay = 225

   # Time in miliseconds before the panel will hide on a leave event
   XfcePanelWindow::popdown-delay = 350
 }
 class "XfcePanelWindow" style "xfce-panel-window-style"
```

`
to the ~/.gtkrc-2.0. It affects all panels (i can't target just one) but...ok.

Comment: I don't have a ~/.gtkrc-2.0 . Should I create it?

Comment: I get the impression that it doesn't respect a value of `0`. You may need to use `1` if you want a really short delay.

Answer (score 1):

As others already stated, the correct answer on this question is as follows (fixed typos from other poster):

Add the following

```
style "xfce-panel-window-style"
 {
   # Time in miliseconds before the panel will unhide on an enter event
   XfcePanelWindow::popup-delay = 225

   # Time in miliseconds before the panel will hide on a leave event
   XfcePanelWindow::popdown-delay = 350
 }
 class "XfcePanelWindow" style "xfce-panel-window-style"
```

to the file `~/.gtkrc-2.0` It will affect all panels.

Unfortunately theres a bit **DOWNSIDE**:

This answer was written when Xfce still had GTK+ 2 components. This means the delay autohide will **not work in Xfce 4.12 and newer**.

Comment: Heres the solution to get it working on versions newer then Xfce 4.12:
https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=13762